# How to get files>5000 in share point

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint location where the total number of files are more than 5000. In this case I am not able to view them in file explorer. Is there any other option to retrieve the files available in sharepoint programatically and not using sharepoint website

Answer (score 0):

You can index the column and use below code :

```
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
## View XML
$qCommand = @"
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@
## Page Position
$position = $null

## All Items
$allItems = @()
Do{
    $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $position
    $camlQuery.ViewXml = $qCommand
 ## Executing the query
    $currentCollection = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
    $ctx.Load($currentCollection)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

 ## Getting the position of the previous page
    $position = $currentCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition

 # Adding current collection to the allItems collection
    $allItems += $currentCollection
}
# the position of the last page will be Null
Until($position -eq $null)
```

This code is resembling the pagination behaviour. 
`$position` will the previous page index.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the code in this post:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128373/large-list-issue-with-csom

Note: you have to use indexed column in the camel query.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("weburl");
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
do
{
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <ViewFields>
                              <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                            </ViewFields>
                            <RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>
                          </View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", listItem["Title"]);
}
while(position != null)
```